# How to properly add a second join in a custom Views relationship handler?

Tags: views, users

I'm developping a Drupal 7 [module](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/pascalanimateur/2499833) that allows text fields to reference entities that have a title / name matching the field's text value. I have successfully exposed Views relationships for these text fields by implementing `text_field_views_data_views_data_alter(&$data, $field)`, for example if I have `field_main_researcher` configured to reference user entities, the relationship looks like:

```
$data['field_data_field_main_researcher']['field_main_researcher_value']['relationship'] = array(
  'label' => t('User entity referenced from field_main_researcher'),
  'group' => t('Text or Entity'),
  'title' => t('Referenced Entity'),
  'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship',
  'base' => 'users',
  'base field' => 'name',
);
```

I'm now trying to add support for the Real Name module, so in the case above I started out by changing `base` and `base field` to `realname` which produces the correct SQL query and allows me to add the Realname field or use it in a contextual filter. **But I need to be able to access the whole user entity, not just the Realname entry!**

Since the [views_handler_relationship](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/handlers!views_handler_relationship.inc/class/views_handler_relationship/7) documentation states this base class can only handle a single join, I set out to implement a custom relationship handler that will add the second join to the query when needed. This is what I've come up with so far:

```
class text_or_entity_handler_relationship extends views_handler_relationship {
  function query() {
    parent::query();
    if (!strcmp($this->definition['base'], 'realname')) {
      $second_join = new views_join();
      $second_join->definition = array(
        'left_table' => 'realname_' . $this->table,
        'left_field' => 'uid',
        'table' => 'users',
        'field' => 'uid',
      );
      $second_join->construct();
      $second_join->adjusted = TRUE;
      $alias = 'users_' . $this->table;
      $this->query->add_relationship($alias, $second_join, 'users');
      $this->query->add_table('users', NULL, $second_join, $alias);
    }
  }
}
```

The above code properly adds the second JOIN on the `users` table and links it to `realname` via the shared `uid` column, **but for some reason I still can't access the user entity fields or contextual filters** despite adding the `users` table to the query!

What am I missing?

Comment: PascalAnimateur it looks like you found a solution for this issue in your module; would you care to write an answer? I was dealing with a similar issue and used a variation on your code to solve it, so thanks for that!

Comment: If I remember correctly, the problem was due to the fact that the target entity type / bundle settings were at the field instance level, which prevented the views_handler_relationship of knowing what entity type could be referenced as it could only access settings from the field base. I hope this helps with your particular situation...